# Insert characters into given string

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a little Ruby program that can insert two letters behind consonants only within a string.  I'm trying to do it using two classes within a main class by passing the characters of a string to the block associated with the class method.  One method would insert the letters, the other would be able to remove them.

Here's what I have so far:

```
class Mytranslator
  def to_mytrans( string )
    letters = string.inject( 'it' ) {|letters, char| collection += char}
    puts letters
  end


  def to_normaltrans( string )

  end
end
```

Problem is, I don't know if I'm even on the right track.  And I have no idea how to write the second method.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Could you add example input and output, what you are expecting. The description doesn't explain it well enough.

Comment: I'm wanting them to be class methods and to call them with something like this:  Mytranslator.to_mytrans( "Some string.") { |c| print c}   and get output like so: "Sitomite sittitritinitgit."  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def to_mytrans(s)
  s.gsub(/([^aeiouAEIOU])/,'\1it')
end

def to_normaltrans(s)
  s.gsub(/([^aeiouAEIOU])it/,'\1')
end
```

This will fail if your string has numbers/punctuation etc.

Comment: How do I turn those methods into class methods?  I'm wanting to call a class method with something like this:    Mytranslator.to_mytrans( "Some string.) { |c| print c}     I'm trying to get output like this:  "Sitomite sittitritinitgit."

Comment: make it def self.to_mytrans(s)